# SOAP request format to update the existing record in Exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can anyone tell me the Update Request format(working format) for SOAP request.I have a data extension and I want to update the user details like FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME and the primary key in my data extension is "Email".

Comment: can you share your current code and highlight where you are stuck or need help ?

Comment: Have you looked at the SOAP packet at the bottom of this page?  Please have a look, and then let us know if you have questions.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/adding_data_to_data_extension_object/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of a working SOAP call.  Tested a few moments ago and confirmed it will add and update the data extension.

```
<soap:Body>
  <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options>
      <SaveOptions>
        <SaveOption>
          <PropertyName>DataExtensionObject</PropertyName>
          <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
        </SaveOption>
      </SaveOptions>
      <RequestType>Asynchronous</RequestType>
    </Options>
    <Objects xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
        <!--
        <Client>
          <ID>12345</ID>
        </Client>
        -->
        <CustomerKey>DESOAPUPDATE</CustomerKey>
        <Properties>
          <Property>
            <Name>SubscriberKey</Name>
            <Value>TestSubscriberKey123</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
            <Value>test@gmail.com</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>FirstName</Name>
            <Value>TestFirstName</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>LastName</Name>
            <Value>TestLastName</Value>
          </Property>
          <Property>
            <Name>City</Name>
            <Value>Indy</Value>
          </Property>
        </Properties>
    </Objects>
  </UpdateRequest>
</soap:Body>
```